# Ключевое слово new в js

Tags: javascript

Как работает ключевое слово `new`?

Сделал несколько тестов, но ничего толкового не узнал.

Все началось с этого кода который я нашел.

```
const
    pattern = ['A','B'],
    times = 5,
    result = Array(times).fill(pattern).flat();

console.log(...result); // A B A B A B A B A B
```

**Почему тут не используется ключевое слово `new`**? Из любопытства я использовал, но результат не изменился.

```
const
    pattern = ['A','B'],
    times = 5,
    result = new Array(times).fill(pattern).flat();

console.log(...result); // A B A B A B A B A B -> тоже самое что и наверху
```

Забавно.

Вот еще тесты.

```
const a = new Array(); // -> a === []
const b = new Array; // -> b === []
const c = Array(); // -> c === []
```

Как это работает?

Comment: Если мы не передаем параметры в конструктор класса, то скобки можно не писать.`new Array() то же самое, что и new Array;`

Comment: Не очень удачный пример для экспериментов выбрали, `Array` является особенным https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5827008

Comment: @entithat спасибо, этого я не знал

Comment: @andreymal спасибо, но я прочитал все эти ссылки прежде чем здесь задать вопрос.

Comment: Кстати, fill делает не то, что ты думаешь.

Comment: @Qwertiy и что делает fill?

Comment: @Demon__, заполняет одним и тем же массивом, а не разными.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Обычные функции могут создавать объекты. Если эти функции назвать с большой буквы, то они будут выглядеть как класс. Им не нужен `new` для работы, они и так создают объект, например так:

```
function MyObject(){
    return { isMySuperObject: true };
}
```

А вот функция-класс, которой требуется `new` для создания точно такого же объекта:

```
function MyObject(){
    this.isMySuperObject = true;
}
```

Так же работает функция Array. Или например стандартная функция `Error`, которую можно писать с `new` или без него, в любом случае она создаёт объект ошибки.

Но не все функции работают одинаково в режиме класса или простой функции. Могут быть нюансы или большие различия. Например стандартная функция `Date` без `new` возвращает строку даты, а с `new` - объект даты.

`new` всегда означает, что в результате будет экземпляр данного класса, то есть объект. А не примитивное значение вроде строки или числа. Потому что именно `new` создаёт новый объект, а функция справа от него наполняет этот объект свойствами.

В отличие от этого, функция, не важно с какой буквы написанная, может вернуть что угодно, а не только объекты.

P.S. Массивы - это объекты. Не совсем, но обычно так говорят, имея в виду что они "передаются по ссылке" как объекты и тоже ведут себя как коробочка со свойствами.